# Drupal - code works in page.tpl.php but wont work in a block

Tags: drupal-theming

The following code works fine in my page.tpl.php but I cant get it to work in a block:

```
<?php if (function_exists('twitter_pull_render')) { print twitter_pull_render('@ahmednuaman', $title = NULL, $num_items = 5); } ?>
```

Ive tried full html and php input formats. Ive tried removing the opening and closing php tags. Ive tried turning off all my input filters.

Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working? I havn't tried putting php in a block before so I might be doing it wrong. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the php input module was disabled, but the php input filter still showed up as an option for the block.